# HTML5 Age Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am required to create a form using HTML5 that has this validation;

Date of birth should be a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. After entering
the DOB, the page should calculate the age and alert the user if he/she is
under 18 with the message “You must be over 18 to register”

Could anyone please make my understand how I code create this validation?
The could below is how my form looks like.

```
<div id="content">
    <article id="contentimg">
        <form action="http://posttestserver.com/post.php" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)" method="post">
        <fieldset style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px;">
            <legend>Enter your information to subscirbe:</legend>
            First name: <input class="glowing-border" type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
            Last name: <input class="glowing-border" type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
            Birthday: <input class="glowing-border" type="date" name="bday"><br>
            Address: <input class="glowing-border2" type="text" name="address"><br>
            Mobile Number: <input class="glowing-border" type="text" name="mobno"><br>
            Email: <input id="email" class="glowing-border" type="email" name="email" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"><br>
            Confirm Email: <input id="confemail" class="glowing-border" type="email" name="email" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}@[a-zA-Z]{3,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" 
            onfocus="validateMail(document.getElementById('email'), this);" oninput="validateMail(document.getElementById('email'), this);"><br>
            <input class="glowing-border" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input class="glowing-border" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click "edit" under your question and post the Javascript that is handling your onSubmit or that otherwise reads your form and compares the Birthday and current date.  If you don't have any javascript yet, the general rule is to write the Javascript that you know and ask when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more idea is

```
 <input type="number" size="4" name="age" min="18" required style="display:none;">
```

add this field and calculate on change Birthday field

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, if it is set to type="text" we can do this onblur or onsubmit

```
function validateDOB(bday) {
  var dateString = bday.value;
  var parts = dateString.split("/"); // not testing if the format is correct here
  var now = new Date();
  var birthday = new Date(now.getFullYear(),parts[1]-1,parts[0]);
  var age = now.getFullYear()-parts[2];
  if (now<birthday) age--;
  if (age<18) {
    alert("You must be over 18 to register");
    return false
  }
  // other validation
  return true;
}
```

I am looking into how to do the same on an HTML5 date field

This does not work for some reason

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LGnn5/)

```
function getDob() {
  var date = new Date();
  return (date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate()+"-"+(date.getFullYear()-18);
}
$(function() {
  $("input[type=date]").prop("max",getDob());
});
```

UPDATE - min/max has little support.

Instead use jQuery date validation

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=date]").prop("max",getDob());
  $("#bday").validate();
});
```

using

```
<input id="bday" required="required"  min="1900-01-01" max="2099-09-13" type="date" >
```

Comment: How would I now implement this onto my javascript file? Also, would I need to change any variable names?

Comment: Just add it in the head of the page in script tags or put it in an external js file and add the script as `<script src="validation.js"></script>` in the head

Comment: Do I need to give the form an id?

Comment: Wait - I am testing this

Comment: This is how my form looks like: http://prntscr.com/3n0hm0

I just want a validation rule with HTML5 that allows me to validate the date the user has inputted and give a message stating that he/she must be over 18 to register.

Comment: See update. There is no built-in validation for all browsers